# Uncooperative ELK Docker Instance

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have ELK 5.5.1 running in a Docker container, and it'll parse most of my logs, except for ones that originate from my Spring application. Kinda running out of ideas.

I've traced it down to the logstash->elasticsearch pipeline. Filebeat is doing its job, and Logstash *is* receiving logs from the application in question, based on tailing lostash's stdout log.

I wiped the docker volume that stores my ELK data clean, and started fresh with filebeat just forwarding the logs in question.

Take a log line like this:

```
FINEST|8384/0|Service tsoft_spring|17-08-31 14:12:01|2017-08-31 14:12:01.260  INFO 8384 --- [ taskExecutor-2] c.t.s.c.s.a.ConfirmationService          : Will not persist empty response notes
```

Using a very minimal logstash configuration, it'll wind up being persisted in elasticsearch:

```
  input {
    beats {
      port => 5044
      ssl => false
    }
  }
  filter {
    if [message] =~ /tsoft_spring/ {
      grok {
         match => [ "message", "%{GREEDYDATA:logmessage}" ]
      }
    }
  }
  output {
    stdout { }
    elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
  }
```

Using a more complete configuration, the log is just ignored by elastic, no grokparsefailure, no dateparsefailure:

```
  input {
    beats {
      port => 5044
      ssl => false
    }
  }
  filter {
    if [message] =~ /tsoft_spring/ {
      grok {
        match => [ "message", "%{WORD}\|%{NUMBER}/%{NUMBER}\|%{WORD}%{SPACE}%{WORD}\|%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\|%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}%{SPACE}%{NUMBER:pid}%{SPACE}---%{SPACE}%{SYSLOG5424SD:threadname}%{SPACE}%{JAVACLASS:classname}%{SPACE}:%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:logmessage}" ]
      }
      date {
        match => [ "timestamp" , "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
      }
    }
  }
  output {
    stdout { }
    elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
  }
```

I've checked that this pattern will parse that line, using http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result, and I could've sworn it was working last weekend, but could be my imagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the problem here is not in your grok filter, but in the date match. Resulting year is 0017, instead of 2017. Maybe that's why you can't find the event in ES? Can you try this:

```
date {
  match => [ "timestamp" , "yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ]
}
```

Comment: son of a gun...I can't believe it. I've seen dateparsefailure before in this case. I cannot believe that - thanks a ton!